# Determine if $G$ is a group under the $\,\gcd\,$ operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G = [1,2,3,4,6,12].\;$ Let $\,a*b = \gcd(a,b), a,b \in G.\;$ Determine whether $G$ is a group.

I have found that for any two elements in $G$, commutativity holds, but the inverses are not unique for some elements i.e. $\gcd(3,4) = \gcd(3,2) = 1$, and the identity is not unique, e.g., $\gcd(2,2) = 2$ but $\gcd(3,3) = 3$.

So $G$ is clearly not a group, is my logic correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes...the failure of *any one* of the group axioms is sufficient reason to conclude $G$ is not a group.

But I think it's worth the time and effort you put in to explore all the ways in which it fails to be a group.

Note: the only element that could possibly be the identity such that $ge = eg = g$ for all $g \in G$ is the element $\;e=12:\; \gcd(g, 12) = \gcd(12, g) = g$ for all $g \in G$, and then knowing that, you can show that for all $\,g\in G g\neq 12$, there does not exist any $g^{-1} \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comments above, you want to check each of the group axiomse

1. It is fairly straightforward to check that associativity holds.
2. Contrary to those comments above, you should be able to find an element that is the identity.
3. Once you have worked out what this identity element is, then (**and only then**) are you in a position to prove that there are no inverse elements).

Comment: $3.$ is not true. As the OP noticed, $\, 3*4 = 3*2,\,$ so $\,3\,$ is not invertible, i.e. there does not exist an identity $\,e\,$ such that $\,3^{-1}\cdot 3 = e\,$ since, if so, then multiplying the prior equation through by $3^{-1}$ yields $\,4 = 2,\,$ contradiction; i.e. invertible elements must be cancellable. One does need to prove an identity exists to make that inference. Thus, if a noncancellable element exists then the operation is not the binary operation of a group.

Answer (score 1):

What @amWhy pointed is enough and I don't know if you are online to see my post or not. Other points that I can add:

Your structure is closed under the given operation and indeed because of the nature of operation `gcd`, we have `a*b=b*a`:

```
gcd(1,1)=1   gcd(1,2)=1   gcd(1,3)=1   gcd(1,4)=1   gcd(1,6)=1   gcd(1,12)=1   

gcd(2,2)=2   gcd(2,3)=1   gcd(2,4)=2   gcd(2,6)=2   gcd(2,12)=2

gcd(3,3)=3   gcd(3,4)=1   gcd(3,6)=3   gcd(3,12)=3

gcd(4,4)=4   gcd(4,6)=2   gcd(4,12)=4

gcd(6,6)=6   gcd(6,12)=6

gcd(12,12)=12
```

And we can easily check that $(G,*)$ is an associative structure so it is a finite **semigroup** under this operation. You have more about $G$, that is $G$ is a **[regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup)** semigroup. Indeed, for every element $a\in G$ the set of elements $x\in G$ in which $a*x*a=a$of is not empty and in fact we have: $$a\in\{x\in G\mid \gcd\left(\gcd(a,x),a\right)=a\}.$$